# Floatrow: multiline caption overlaps subsequent float

Tags: captions, floatrow

I am trying to create two subfigures with their own caption and a common caption using [floatrow](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/floatrow/floatrow.pdf). However the caption for the figure containing the two subfigures is not adjusted in size if it covers mutliple lines, resulting in it overlapping subsequent content. I made the overlapped caption red so that it becomes even more apparent.

How do I get floatrow to account for the multiline caption(i.e. get rid of the overlap)?

[image: Overlapping heading]

```
\documentclass{muthesis}

\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\DeclareCaptionSubType[alph]{figure}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=brace,textfont=md,labelfont=up,labelsep=space}

\floatsetup[figure]{valign=t,heightadjust=all,subfloatrowsep=qquad}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \ffigbox[\linewidth]{%
        \begin{subfloatrow}[2]%
            \ffigbox[\linewidth]{%
                \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=1em]{}%
                \caption{Send}%
                \label{fig:a}%
            }{}%
            \ffigbox[\linewidth]{%
                \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=2em]{}%
                \caption{Receive}%
                \label{fig:b}%
            }{}%
        \end{subfloatrow}%
        \caption{ Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus.  }%
        \label{fig:subfig}%
    }{}%
\end{figure}

\begin{table}
    \ttabbox{%
        \begin{tabular}{ll}
            a&b\\
        \end{tabular}%
        \caption{\color{red}Overlapped}%
        \label{tab:a}%
    }{}
\end{table}

\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for accepting the answer, you could upvote at once ;-)

Comment: @Tarass: I was reluctant, as I first had to figure out what your fix was (I saw it working). I currently can not accept the answer, as my actual problem has an additional challenge: the images have different height. The mwe above is adjusted to account for this. In the MWE the images will align to their top edge (after running tex twice), adding the `style=plain` fixes the overlap of the caption, but it also causes the `valign=t, heightadjust=all` keys to be overriden, which cause the images to align to their top edges in the first place. Can I prevent the overflwo and keep my alignment?

Comment: I have not such a problem, the images stay aligned on the bottom. Or I missunderstund your point ? See my edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`heightadjust=all` needs to be changed to `heightadjust=object` inside the initial float setup.

[image]

```
\documentclass{muthesis}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{floatrow}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\DeclareCaptionSubType[alph]{figure}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=brace,textfont=md,labelfont=up,labelsep=space}

\floatsetup[figure]{valign=t,heightadjust=object,subfloatrowsep=qquad}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \ffigbox[\linewidth]{%
        \begin{subfloatrow}[2]%
            \ffigbox[\linewidth]{%
                \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{monkey-selfie}%
                \caption{Send}%
                \label{fig:a}%
            }{}%
            \ffigbox[\linewidth]{%
                \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{sc-teacher}%
                \caption{Receive}%
                \label{fig:b}%
            }{}%
        \end{subfloatrow}%
        \caption{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus.  }%
        \label{fig:subfig}%
    }{}%
\end{figure}



\begin{table}[h]
    \ttabbox{%
        \begin{tabular}{ll}
            a&b\\
        \end{tabular}%
        \caption{\color{red}Overlapped}%
        \label{tab:a}%
    }{}
\end{table}

\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: While your solution works for my MWE, the actual case is slightly more complicated. `style=plain` overrides the previous keys, I will adjust my MWE. (+1 though)

Comment: Did you try `style=Plaintop` ?

Comment: `Plaintop` moves the caption above the images. I want the images to be aligned by their top edges (i.e. Figure 2 should move up, while the captions stay). And I am actually going for the `subfloatrow` as the two figures are closely related (think figure 2 Apes, a) male b) female). However you pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: I added my fix, your idea of adding `style=plain` pointed me in the right direction, one of my setup keys must have been wrong, see edited version to see what I went with in the end. P.S.: I think the `capbesideposition` key is not necessary either way. If you accept the edit, I will accept the answer

Comment: I tried with you new proposal, my two images stay aligned on bottom edges. Don't you want images aligned on top edges and caption beside ?

Comment: Thats odd, I added an edit with a picture showing the result I get when running the code from the question, but replacing `heightadjust=all` with `heightadjust=object`. Note: run Latex twice after making this change. (Not sure whats going on but I assume something is calculated on the first run and those updated numbers only come in on the second run after making changes)

Comment: Oh, by the way I am not looking for besides captions, what is in the image is what I am looking for (small captions for the subfigures underneath, and one caption for the group of subfigures, also underneath). if there is more to discuss we should move to chat.